# Python: failed to send mail attachment, empty file is sent

Tags: python, email

I'm using the following code to send mail attachment, sometimes it succeed but other times it sends an empty file. I know that the reading of the file finish successfully. Anyone got any idea what is wrong with my code?

```
import smtplib
import os
from os.path import basename
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.utils import COMMASPACE, formatdate


msg = MIMEMultipart()
msg['From'] = **************
msg['To'] = **************
msg['Date'] = formatdate(localtime=True)
msg['Subject'] = “Hi"

msg.attach(MIMEText("text"))

f = "myzip.zip"

fil = open(f, "rb")
x =  fil.read()
fil.close()
part = MIMEApplication(x,Name=basename(f))
part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="%s"' % basename(f)
msg.attach(part)


smtp = smtplib.SMTP("127.0.0.1")
smtp.sendmail(“*****************", “********************", msg.as_string())
smtp.close()
```

Edit:
I've noticed that usually when I try to send specific file few times, the first time usually succeed.

Comment: I assume the curly-quotes are an artifact of editing the code on this site, not part of your original code?

Comment: Also, are you on 3.6 or later? If so, `email.contentmanager` is a lot harder to get wrong than manually doing the `email.mime` stuff (except in the cases that `contentmanager` can't handle, of course). Is that a possible option for you?

Comment: Meanwhile: You're talking to a local SMTP server. Can you look at its logs (or, ideally, configure it to log entire SMTP sessions) to see if it's getting the right thing?

Comment: The curly-quotes are indeed an artifact of editing the code on this site (to hide my private details). Unfortunely my python version is 2.7 and I've got no permission to view the server logs :(

Comment: If you've got no permission to view the server logs, just run another SMTP server on port 9925, configured to log all complete transactions, and change your code to point at 127.0.0.1:9995.